# storing more than 255 characters in a PostgreSQL DB on heroku

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am using heroku, and in doing so, am experiencing my first foray into postgresql. Maybe I just never came across it in development, but I am unable to save entries into my database that are longer than 255 characters. Is there a way around this? Currently the I am just using strings to store message data.

Secondly, if there is indeed a way to store more than 255 characters, is there a good way to convert my message strings into this form, using migrations? My app is currently live and in use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use `text` instead of `string` on your migration type.

---

To change a migration

1. `script/generate migration change_string_to_text`
2. `change_column :model, :attribute, :text`
3. `rake db:migrate`

Comment: is there any way to change the type existing string columns using migrations?

Comment: this is perfect, thank you. i didn't know migrations could alter attributes

Comment: In ActiveRecord 3.0.9 I had to use `change_column :model, :attribute, :text, :limit => nil`, otherwise `db/schema.rb` would contain `t.text "attribute", :limit => 255` after migrating.

Comment: @clacke: This was fixed sometime before 3.2.11

Answer (score 9):

Just to expand on @Codeglot's answer, `:text` is for (essentially) unlimited-length strings.  `:string` with a `limit:1234` option will limit the string to that length.  On Postgres, a `:string, limit:nil` is effectively synonymous with `:text`.  Although some databases store VARCHAR, VARCHAR(n), and TEXT types in different ways, leading to performance considerations, Postgres stores them all in the same way.

So if you want to exceed 255 chars but not be *completely* unbounded, you can use `:string, limit:1234`.  Alternatively, you can use `:text` and restrict the length via validations.