# PostgreSQL string(255) limit - Rails, Ruby and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

So I have a `comments` table that is structured like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: comments
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  body       :string(255)
#  notified   :boolean
#  user_id    :integer
#  stage_id   :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  client_id  :integer
#  author     :string(255)
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
```

How do I store long text in a PG column using Rails 3.x and Heroku?

What would the migration look like to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for anything more than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103141/storing-more-than-255-characters-in-a-postgresql-db-on-heroku ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You would need to use text instead of string.

Migration would be something along the lines of:

```
change_column :comments, :body, :text, :limit => nil
```

Comment: One change to that I would make is, make sure to specify `:limit => nil`, otherwise a `limit` of 255 will be added to the schema in Rails 3.x.

Comment: The `limit:nil` is no longer necessary.  Using rails 3.2.11, setting type to :text sets the Postgres column type to 'text'.  There is no implicit limit:255.

Comment: Rails 3.2.8 , :limit => nil is needed.

Comment: I ran this migration the other day using 4.0.3 and needed the limit => nil.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I just did this in rails 4.0.3 (hosting on heroku) and did not need to set this to nil in order for it to work. It is strange that some seem to need to do so and others dont.

Answer (score 0):

All the time I solve this problem by this type of query 
`ALTER TABLE your_table_name ALTER COLUMN your_column_name TYPE text;`

**Character varying** has limited length and you can not pass this length.
**text** is a variable which has no limit.
So you can convert your column type from character varying(which has a length) to
text (which has no limit).