# Running a Rails app on Heroku with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, oauth, devise

I am trying to setup a Rails app on Heroku using PG, and also using devise and oauth to interact with the Yahoo Sports api.

I am running into an issue where when the users goes to authenticate the Heroku logs are telling me:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
```

So after reading this Stack Overflow post [PostgreSQL string(255) limit - Rails, Ruby and Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784622), I tried changing the token to text from string since that seemed to be the longest thing that may be causing the over 255 limit. My migration looked like this:

```
class AddAccessTokenToAuthentications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :authentications, :token, :text, :limit => nil
    add_column :authentications, :secret, :string
  end
 end
```

However for some reason it seems to be changing everything to text. When I look at my schema after migrating it shows:

```
create_table "authentications", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.text     "provider",   :limit => 255
  t.text     "uid",        :limit => 255
  t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  t.text     "token",      :limit => 255
  t.text     "secret",     :limit => 255
 end
```

When I push to Heroku and try to migrate on Heroku I am getting this error:

```
   -- create_table("authentications", {:force=>true})
     NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "authentications_id_seq" for serial column "authentications.id"
   rake aborted!
   PG::Error: ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "text"
   LINE 1: ...serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "provider" text(255),...
   : CREATE TABLE "authentications" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "provider" text(255), "uid" text(255), "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "token" text(255), "secret" text(255))
```

I am not sure how to resolve this or what I should be looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "text"
```

means you can't use `:limit`

What you can do is either:

```
t.text "provider" # = varchar(max)
```

or

```
t.string "provider",   :limit => 2147483647 # for max limit based on your db
```

Comment: where would I do that in the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Your `text` fields are unable to have a limit on them. Perhaps you meant  to use `string` instead?

Comment: can I change the string limit?

Comment: my understanding was that the pg string limit is 255 and since the stuff I am trying to save is longer than that it is causing an error, therefore I need to change the type to text, but now it seems thats not working for some reason

Comment: If you're going to be using text then, get rid of the `:limit` options after them.